# Count common characters between two string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I need some help with a SQL statement.

I would like to count common characters between string A and B. 
I have the table like that.

```
  A      B    Result
---------------------
13456   124      2
13478   344      2
79105   782      1
12457   983      0
41295   129      3
43134   343      2
86761   676      2
55444   545      2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for an sql statement or a linq query?

Comment: Your output is a bit off here I think. 43134, 343 returns 2. But 55444, 545 returns 3. And what bout 86761, 676? That returns 2, why not 3? More importantly is what are you using this logic for? This type of thing is an indication that something is not quite right in the data model.

Comment: Thank you Sean Lange for your reply. I am sorry. I already edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tally table will be very useful here. I keep one on my system as view. Here is the code for my tally table. It is super fast and has zero reads.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Before we can do anything we need some sample data. I tossed this into a table variable for convenience in demonstrating.

```
declare @Something table (String1 varchar(10), String2 varchar(10))

insert @Something values
('13456', '124')
, ('13478', '344')
, ('79105', '782')
, ('12457', '983')
, ('41295', '129')
, ('43134', '343')
, ('86761', '676')
, ('55444', '545')
```

Now we just need to leverage this table to our advantage. This produces the desired output as stated in the original question.

```
select String1
    , String2
    , Result = sum(CharCount)
from
(
    select String1
        , String2
        , Charcount = max(case when CHARINDEX(substring(String2, t.N, 1), String1, 0) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    from @Something s
    join cteTally t on t.N <= len(String2)
    group by String1
        , String2
        , substring(String2, t.N, 1)
) x
group by String1
        , String2
order by String1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar-valued function along these lines could do the job, rough and dirty:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountCommonChars (
@var1 varchar(10), 
@var2 varchar(10)
)
RETURNS INT
AS

BEGIN

declare @i int = 0,
    @s char(1) = '',
    @t int = 0

while @i<=9
begin

set @s = convert(char(1),@i)

set @t = @t + (case when charindex(@s,@var1)>0 
    and charindex(@s,@var2)>0 then 1 else 0 end)

set @i=@i+1

end

RETURN @t;

END
```

And then something like this:

```
select dbo.CountCommonChars('12345','316')
```

Would result in 2.  So your final query could be:

```
select A, B, Result = dbo.CountCommonChars(A,B)
from tbl
```

Comment: Scalar function are notoriously poor performers. And adding a while loop is a recipe for super slow stuff. A tally table would be better than a loop. Here is an excellent article on how a tally table can be used instead of loops. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: Agreed, like I said, rough and dirty

Comment: Thank you for answering.